# Почему не обрабатывается событие MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN?

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте!
Столкнулся с проблемой, переопределяю листание **scrollview**, и чтобы определить куда мы листаем, отлавливаю событие нажатия и поднятия пальца, но событие нажатия не обрабатывается  по неизвестной мне причине.

```
scrollView.setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {

                if( MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN == event.getAction())
                {
                    oldCY = event.getY();//в эту ветку вообще не заходит
                    Toast.makeText(choseDate.this,"down",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    if(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction())
                    {
                        newCY = event.getY();
                        //если мы пролистали вниз, то перелистнем на страницу
                        if(newCY - oldCY > 0)
                        {
                            //сделаем проверку, что мы можешь еще листать
                            if((scrollTo - 72*4)>=0)
                            {
                                scrollTo -=72*4;
                                PostScroller ps = new PostScroller(scrollView,0,scrollTo);
                                scrollView.post(ps);
                            }

                        }
                        if(newCY - oldCY < 0)
                        {
                            //сделаем проверку, что мы можешь еще листать
                            if((scrollTo + 72*4)<=((createdate.MAXYEAR/4)-1)*72)
                            {
                                scrollTo += 72*4;
                                PostScroller ps = new PostScroller(scrollView,0,scrollTo);
                                scrollView.post(ps);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: А точно надо на scrollView  надо это вешать? и точно вы "трогаете" scrollView? Что у вас конкретно листается?

Comment: в scrollview таблица с кнопками, и да, вешать надо, так как реализованное листание не удовлетворяет требованиям.

Comment: да-да точно scrollView же контейнер) чего-то стормозил

Comment: И все-таки мне кажется так спокойно на scrollView не повесить обработчик %) Почему-то я думаю, что событие перехватывают View внутри. Может попробывать, что-то вроде повесить на детей и вызвать onTouchEvent у родителя (попробуйте хотя бы)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну поскольку scrollview это контейнер и сам не обрабатывает ивенты (а только его дочерние), то нужно наследовать субкласс и переопределить метод

[public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29)

И еще: может тут всё таки подойдёт переопределение onScroll?

```
@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
                        float distanceY) {
    return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если у Вас в xml разметки что то вроде такого

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</RelativeLayout>
```

</ScrollView>

То тут вы должны обрабатывать нажатия на RelativeLayout, так как он перекрывает ScrollView

Comment: Нет RelativeLayout это тоже контейнер. Значит ловить ивенты будут его внутренние элементы